# DateTime format full month not as documented

Tags: php, datetime, format

Trying to output the full month name using DateTime object but somehow I'm not interpet [documentation show here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) .

I want the date out put a date like 18 November 2012 but Im not sucseeding

```
$date = new DateTime();
$datum =  $date->format("d m Y");
```

outputs 18 11 2012  ??

reading on this format `dd ([ \t.-])* m ([ \t.-])* y` should output correct but this does not work at all ??

Answer (score 12):

For the formatting characters, see the [`date()` manual page](http://php.net/date). This is referred to several times on the [`DateTime::format()` manual page](http://php.net/datetime.format).

For the full month name you want to use the formatting character `F`.

> A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March

---

The "Date Formats" manual page that you linked to is for the *input* date string, not the output format.

Comment: Silly me, somehow I can't find it on the php.net website?? found something here though: http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time thanks for point me out!